# sessions value still showing on some pages after deleting the session

Tags: php, session

My `sessions` still shows values of sessions that are deleted on some pages. My header has the session start on every page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

I unset my session with:

```
  $key_to_remove = $_POST['key'];  
if (count($_SESSION["Carray"]) <= 1) {
    unset($_SESSION["Carray"]);
} else {
    unset($_SESSION["Carray"]["$key_to_remove"]);
    sort($_SESSION["Carray"]);
}
```

Comment: Have you joined that page with any other page using `include` or `require` which could potentially be making the variable again?

Comment: have include('ajax/mobileredirect.php'); which is for redirecting to mobile version after the session_start();

Comment: Are you by any chances using the same sessions in the mobileredirect.php?

Comment: HawasKaPujaari there are no session in mobileredirect.php

Answer (score 0):

Try This I use this kind of code for destroy session and it's working.

```
<?php
 session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    if(isset($_SESSION['key'])) 
    { 
        unset($_SESSION['carry']);
    }?>
```